# Dual Boot on win8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

My system is not going to dual boot options. I'm new to linux, just wanted to see how it works and so I installed it using a liveUSB after creating a separate 30 Gb partition alongside with my 3 partitions on windows(I think i used an empty 300Gb Partition for the 30 gb, didn't used my C(windows partition) for it) and booted with USB.gave 6000 gb out of 6144 RAM n did proper allocations for swap n boot and everything else n installed it. Now I can't seem to access my windows or any of the data. I had some big projects on those drives.

---

Is there any way I can retrieve all/most of my data! and 
 How'd I know if all of my data has been deleted or if it's still there!

---

I found somewhere I shouldn't use Ubuntu OS as there's a chance it's still overwriting on my old data.
Also I found
[Ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) ,
[SystemRescue] &
[BootRepair]
But I don't know where to start the process of recovering which I hope is still there
**Details** on my laptop:
Model: Dell Inspiron 15 Series
OS before: win8.1
OS tried: Ubuntu 14.04
RAM: 6Gb
Hard Disk: 1Tb
processor: Intel i5
BootInfoScript result: [pastebin results.txt](http://pastebin.com/s8THAqKJ)

Comment: What happened? Can you boot Windows? Can you access its partition? Maybe a `sudo update-grub` would make it show up?

Comment: It's very unclear what your current system state is. Please boot an Ubuntu live disk and run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) utility. This will create a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. That will give us some idea of what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: @RodSmith [pastebin results.txt](http://pastebin.com/s8THAqKJ)

Answer (score 0):

U could go through the link [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

This will fix the loader and u will dual boot.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: Should I do the installation using Try Ubuntu in ubuntu live usb?

Comment: Yeah, and check my updated answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Your Boot Info Script output indicates that you've accidentally overwritten your Windows partitions when you installed Ubuntu. You cannot fully recover from this problem. The best you can do is:

1. ***STOP USING THE DISK IMMEDIATELY!*** Any further use, including booting Ubuntu, runs the risk of making matters worse.
2. If you don't have it already, buy sufficient storage to hold your personal files.
3. Boot an Ubuntu live CD or something similar.
4. Use [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to recover your files individually, using your backup disk as the target.
5. Re-install Windows.
6. Re-install Ubuntu, if desired, but be more careful about your installation options.
7. Restore your personal data from the backup.

Note that there are tools other than PhotoRec that do similar jobs. I've heard that some Windows-specific tools can do a better job of recovering filenames, so you may want to use one of them rather than PhotoRec; but I have no specific URLs or program names. Such tools may require booting from their own recovery disks or from Windows recovery disks rather than from an Ubuntu recovery disk.

Note that the odds of recovering all of your personal files are low. There's a chance you'll recover nothing, although that is also unlikely. Chances are you'll get some fraction of your files.

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news.